# Receber vários inputs em tag html com Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

Em meu app component, estou enviando os seguintes inputs para o html. Como faço para receber todos eles no html?

```
export class AppComponent {
  nomeRedeSocial: string = "Minha Rede Social";
  linhaDoTempo: string = "Linha do Tempo";
  perfil: string = "Perfil";
  usuario: string = "Usuário";
}

<header-fix [usuario]="usuario"></header-fix>
```

Só consigo receber 1 input.

Answer (score 1):

Se o componente  for um componente que você está criando, você pode adicionar mais inputs para poder receber os parâmetros desejados, usando o [@Input decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#inputs-outputs):

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './seu-template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./seus-estilos.css'],
    selector: 'header-fix'
})
export class HeaderFixComponent{

@Input() nomeRedeSocial: string;
@Input() linhaDoTempo: string;
@Input() perfil: string;
@Input() usuario: string;

//...
```

E no AppComponent:

**HTML**

```
<header-fix 
    [usuario]="usuario" 
    [linhaDoTempo]="linhaDoTempo" 
    [perfil]="perfil" 
    [nomeRedeSocial]="nomeRedeSocial">
</header-fix>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
    nomeRedeSocial: string = "Minha Rede Social";
    linhaDoTempo: string = "Linha do Tempo";
    perfil: string = "Perfil";
    usuario: string = "Usuário";
}
```